# Multiple Apache Servers with Multiple Virtual Servers

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, wamp, hosts-file, virtual-host

I have one computer.
I am running two instances of 2 differently installed Apache servers.

1 via WAMP
1 via Zend Framework

I wish for wamp to be connected towards "karl.local"
And for Zend to be connected via "zend.local"

Now i have in the Windows HOSTS file:

```
127.0.0.1   karl.local
127.0.0.2   zend.local
```

And in each on the apaches httpd.conf file:

```
# WAMP Apache
Listen  80

# Zend Apache
Listen 127.0.0.2:8080
```

(Yes I have the whole: "< VirtualHost..." included at the bottom of each conf file)

This isn't working, "zend.local" is still pointing towards my wamp server and not the zend one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Listen 80
```

in your WAMP-Apache config is a catchall, it listens to every localhost address. You should specify

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```